# Default value selection in Bootstrap Multiselect using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for my multiselect boxes. I have data in form of :

```
myData='<option value="tomata selected">Tomata</option>'
```

I am appending it to my multiselect box. and then i am firing

```
$("#myFeild").multiselect('rebuild');
```

But this is not giving me Tomata as selected. I need this field to be preselected. How can this be achieved in bootstrap. This kind of logic works in chosen. i need something similar in boostrap to avoid major function change while migrating from chosen to bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing to this,

```
myData='<option value="tomata" selected>Tomata</option>'
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<select name="country" id="ddldrawDays" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = 'Sunday,Monday,Friday';
        var valArr = data.split(",");
        var i = 0, size = valArr.length;
        for (i; i < size; i++) {
            $('#ddldrawDays').multiselect('select', valArr[i]);
        }
});
</script>
```